# C# List<MyClass> should return a Attribute from the MyClass

Tags: c#, list, attributes

MyClass.cs

```
 public class MyClass
 {
        private string name;

        public string Name
        {
            get { return name; }
            set { name = value; }
        }

        private string path;

        public string Path
        {
            get { return path; }
            set { path= value; }
        }
 }
```

When I return a List of Type MyClass, I would like to have, only the NAME Attribute.. Not the whole object.. How I can achieve this?
Something like:

```
List<MyClass> myClasses = new List<MyClass>();
return myClasses["Name"];  //<--- Only the Name
```

Comment: you want to return a list of names?

Comment: Do you want to return a sequence of strings (each representing a name) or a sequence of `MyClasses` with the `Path`s 'erased' in some way?

Comment: a sequence of MyClasses with the Paths 'erased', a List of Strings(Names)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use Linq to only return the name but you will now have a `List<string>`:

```
return myClasses.Select(x => x.Name).ToList();
```

Alternatively you could create a new list of `MyClass` from your original and only populate the name attibute:

```
return myClasses.Select(x => new MyClass {Name = x.Name}).ToList();
```

Comment: @ssg - you have to be if you want to beat Mr Skeet!

Answer (score 0):

If you just want a list of Names then the `.Select(x => x.Name)` mentioned by others is the best.

If however you want to return an object that only has the Name property, you could use an interface.

```
public interface IName
{ 
    string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Then make MyClass implement the interface

```
public class MyClass: IName
{
    //...snip
}
```

Then you can return a list of the interface

```
return myClasses.Cast<IName>();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public class myList : List<MyClass>
{
    public MyClass this[string SearchedName]
    {
        get
        {
            return this.SingleOrDefault(mc => mc.Name == SearchedName);
        }
    }
}
```